# MongoDB aggreagate query to get list of each element and its count for each record

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my mongodb, i have few collections, i want to create a new collection by comparing the collection 1 and collection 2 using pymongo.

```
    Collection 1 :
    Object id       timestamp                          Prof_Name   subjects1 
    abc67478898k  ISODate("2018-01-03T09:26:37.541Z")   ABDC      "sub1, sub2, sub3"
    jjjjjjjjjj    ISODate("2018-01-03T09:26:37.541Z")   XYZ       "sub2, sub4, sub8"

    Collection 2 :
    Object id   timestamp               UUID   subjects2            rating score
    3333333    ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  7897  "sub1,sub4, sub7"     7      10
    444444     ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  4532   "sub2"               4      6
    777777     ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  7876  "sub1,sub2,sub3"      8      8
    1111111    ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")   654   "sub1,sub3"          7      8
```

I'm getting my 3 collection, for each subject by Prof_name find matching subjects in collection2 and the UUID and UUID_count between a certain timestamp and my mongo query is as below:

```
    db.data1.aggregate([
      {"$lookup":{
        "from":"data2",
        "let":{"subject":{"$split":["$SUBJECT",", "]}},
        "pipeline":[
          {"$match": {"expr":{"$and":[{"$eq":[{"$year":"$timestamp"}, 2016]}, {"$eq":[{"$month":"$timestamp"}, 1]}]}}},
          {"$addFields":{"SUBJECT_ID":{"$split":["$SUBJECT_ID",", "]},"SUBJECT":"$$subject"}},
          {"$unwind":"$SUBJECT"},
          {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$SUBJECT","$SUBJECT_ID"]}}},
          {"$facet":{
            "UUID":[{"$group":{"_id":{"id":"$_id","UUID":"$UUID"}}},{"$count":"UUID_Count"}],
            "REST":[
              {"$group":{"_id":null,"subjects_list":{"$addToSet":"$SUBJECT"},"UUID_distinct_list":{"$addToSet":"$UUID"}}},
              {"$addFields":{"subject_count":{"$size":"$subjects_list"},"UUID_distinct_count":{"$size":"$UUID_distinct_list"}}},
              {"$project":{"_id":0}}
             ]
          }},
          {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$UUID",0]},{"$arrayElemAt":["$REST",0]}]}}}
        ],
        "as":"ref_data"
      }},
      {"$unwind":{"path":"$ref_data","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
      {"$addFields":{"ref_data.Prof_Name":"$Prof_Name"}},
      {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$ref_data"}},
      {"$out":"data3"}
    ])
```

Above query gives me below collection.

```
    Collection 3 :

     objectid  Prof_name subjects_list  UUID_list           UUID-count subject_count
        12       ABDC      sub1,sub2,sub3 7897,4532,7876,654  4            3
        34       XYZ       sub2,sub4,sub8 7897,4532,7876      2            3
```

Now i want to get another column for my collection 3 which says list of count for each subject and UUID associated with each subject, something like this 
        Collection 3 :

```
     objectid  Prof_name subjects_list  UUID_list           UUID-count subject_count each_sub_count             UUID-assocaited_sub
        12       ABDC      sub1,sub2,sub3 7897,4532,7876,654  4           3         sub1:3,sub2:2,sub3:2    [sub1:7897,7876,654, sub2:4532,7876, sub3:7876]
        34       XYZ       sub2,sub4,sub8 7897,4532,7876      2           3         sub2:2,sub4:1,sub8:0    [sub2:4532,7876, sub4:7897,sub8:0]
```

Last 2 column is what i need, how do i achieve this, possible to modify above query and get it or what is the new query to get these columns.

Comment: @Veeram Can you please have a look on this

Comment: @Veeram how do i modify this query to add  new columns from collection 1 and collection2 both.. For example "timestamp" column from collection1 and rating column from collection2 in collection3 ( data3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include another pipeline in `$facet`.

```
{"$facet":{
  "UUID":[{"$group":{"_id":{"id":"$_id","UUID":"$UUID"}}},{"$count":"UUID_Count"}],
  "COUNT":[
     {"$group":{"_id":null,"subjects_list":{"$addToSet":"$SUBJECT"},"UUID_distinct_list":{"$addToSet":"$UUID"}}},
     {"$addFields":{"subject_count":{"$size":"$subjects_list"},"UUID_distinct_count":{"$size":"$UUID_distinct_list"}}},
     {"$project":{"_id":0}}
  ],
  "SUB":[
     {"$group":{"_id":"$SUBJECT","count":{"$sum":1}," UUID_list":{"$push":"$UUID"}}},
     {"$group":{"_id":null,"each_sub_count":{"$push":{"sub":"$_id", "count":"$count"}},"UUID-assocaited_sub":{"$push":{"sub":"$_id", uuids:"$UUID_list"}}}},
     {"$project":{"_id":0}}
  ]
}},
{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$UUID",0]},{"$arrayElemAt":["$COUNT",0]}, {"$arrayElemAt":["$SUB",0]}]}}}
```